# Why do trap sometimes ignore signals?

Tags: bash, signals, trap

I have the following script

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
trap "{ echo bye ;}" SIGINT


while :
do 
                echo "Hello"
done
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> the while loop is not stopped and `echo bye` is not executed.

The same thing happens if I have:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
trap "{ echo bye ;}" SIGINT


while echo -n ""
do 
                echo "Hello"
done
```

why does trap ignore the `SIGINT` signal?

Answer (score 2):

The `echo bye` is executed, but you can't see it. Try adding `sleep 0.5` to your while loop and you'll see it.

The while loop isn't stopped because your `trap` has used the Ctrl/C. You need to add an `exit` command to your `trap` if you want the code to exit:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
gotcha()
{
    echo "Bye"
    exit 1
}

trap gotcha SIGINT

while :
do 
    echo "Hello"
    sleep 0.5
done
```

One really important thing to understand about the `trap` feature is that it will not fire until the current command (whatever that is) in the script has finished executing. So you cannot necessarily use it to interrupt a long-running command.

Comment: nice explanation, however I wonder why if I use another command after while instead `:` for example `date` the loop is interrupted?

Comment: @sebelk `date` is not a builtin. Each `date` in the loop will be a separate process that doesn't ignore `SIGINT`. Upon Ctrl+C the terminal sends `SIGINT` to the entire foreground process group. If some `date` runs at the moment, it's in the group. If it breaks because of `SIGINT` then it will fail. If it fails then the loop will end because this is how `while` works.